# Sharepoint 2010 - Sample code to create Subsite using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint development.

I have a requirement to create subsite in sharepoint server with the help of visual studio 2010. I need a code to create a subsite when a user add a new list item in the sharepoint site. I used EventListViewer to call the Add Item event. Please guide me how to work on this issue.

I am sharing the code i used in event receiver

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
        base.ItemAdding(properties);
        try
        {
            WriteLog("Process started", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit );

            // Get Properties
            string name = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();
            string description = properties.ListItem["Description"].ToString();
            DateTime startDate = (DateTime)properties.ListItem["Start Date"];
            DateTime endDate = (DateTime)properties.ListItem["End Date"];

            // Create sub site
            SPWeb web = properties.OpenSite().AllWebs.Add(name.Replace(" ", string.Empty), name,
                description, 0, SPWebTemplate.WebTemplateSTS, false, false);
            web.Update();

            WriteLog("Process Completed", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog("Error:" + ex.Message + "  StackTrace --" + ex.StackTrace, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is really trivial. Did you search on Google with 'sp210 create site c#'. Besides that you need to use a list item eventreceiver. If you need more help share your code and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Hi Neils, i shared the code with you. Please look into it and let me know how to correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Does it throw an exception. I see some possible issues though:

- the code is run in the context of the user which created the item. You're not sure that user has access to the site collection or permission to create a new site. You might consider using an elevated prompt.

- You should dispose the created web by wrapping it in a `using` statement

Comment: Thanks for your response neil. I didnt received any exception when i debug the code. Also i tried the elevator permissions to the above code but no solution.